# Android Button Scale Animation

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, button

I just want to make my image button to do the Scale (little zoom in&out repetedly) animation when the app starts, in the first screen, till I press it. That's because this is the 'main' and the most important button of the app and I want to draw the attention of the user. I have found some tutorials and I reached this far:

**MainScreen.java**

```
package com.example.konarx.a11042016;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn;
final Animation scale; //ERROR - Variable 'scale' might not have been initialized//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    final scale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gps_button_animation); //ERROR - Unknown class: 'scale'//
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton); //ERROR - Unexpected cast to `Button`: layout tag was `ImageButton`//
    btn.startAnimation(scale); //I just want to do the animation without clicking it. Is that going to work?//
}

public void InfoActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**gps_button_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="3.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

**Button xml in main_activity.xlm**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />
```

Please help :(

ps: I'm newbie, this is my first app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to initialize your button

```
btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
```

Now, you need to set this button on a clickListener.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Add to your class declaration

```
    public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
       private ImageButton btn;
       private Animation scale;
```

The last thing to do is to add the clickListener and start the animation

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             btn.startAnimation(scale);
        }
```

.

```
    public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btn;
    private Animation scale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        scale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gps_button_animation);
      btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton); 
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btn.startAnimation(scale); //gives me error to scale//
    }

    public void InfoActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Hope that solves your problem. If you have questions to this, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: see the changes I've done to the MainScreen.java. It gives me errors to
**(Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);** and **btn.startAnimation(scale);**

Comment: and you have to import Button

Comment: (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton); should go into the onCreate...

Comment: First of all thank you for your time. You are the only one who answered. Please see the latest changes I've done and read the comments in the lines I've left for you. Thank you again!

Comment: look at my code! remove the final in front of Animation scale. Im sorry for the problem with the button. You should write (ImageButton). And private ImageButton btn;